# Unnormalized Kauffman homology of the unknot

Tags: knot-theory, categorification, khovanov-homology

Is the unnormalized Kauffman homology of the unknot known? The Poincare polynomial of HOMFLY homology of the unknot is known as 
$$\frac{1+at}{1-q}.$$
Is the Poincare polynomials of Kauffman homology of the unknot obtained?
 The [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701333) of Khovano-Rozansky considered a categorification of SO(2N) Kauffman polynomial. Is there any difference between SO(2N+1) ($B_n$) and SO(2N) ($D_n$)?